# C# "Generator" Method

Tags: c#, foreach, generator, enumerator

I come from the world of Python and am trying to create a "generator" method in C#. I'm parsing a file in chunks of a specific buffer size, and only want to read and store the next chunk one at a time and yield it in a `foreach` loop. Here's what I have so far (simplified proof of concept):

```
class Page
{
    public uint StartOffset { get; set; }
    private uint currentOffset = 0;

    public Page(MyClass c, uint pageNumber)
    {
        uint StartOffset = pageNumber * c.myPageSize;

        if (StartOffset < c.myLength)
            currentOffset = StartOffset;
        else
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Page offset exceeds end of file");

        while (currentOffset < c.myLength && currentOffset < (StartOffset + c.myPageSize))
            // read data from page and populate members (not shown for MWE purposes)
            . . .
    }
}

class MyClass
{
    public uint myLength { get; set; }
    public uint myPageSize { get; set; }

    public IEnumerator<Page> GetEnumerator()
    {
        for (uint i = 1; i < this.myLength; i++)
        {
            // start count at 1 to skip first page
            Page p = new Page(this, i);
            try
            {
                yield return p;
            }
            catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
            {
                // end of available pages, how to signal calling foreach loop?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know this is not perfect since it is a minimum working example (I don't allow many of these properties to be set publicly, but for keeping this simple I don't want to type private members and properties).

However, **my main question** is how do I let the caller looping over MyClass with a foreach statement know that there are no more items left to loop through? Is there an exception I throw to indicate there are no elements left?

Comment: You simply stop yielding items, just like in Python. That being said, you should make a method that returns an `IEnumerable<BTreePage>`; enumerables are easier to consume.

Comment: `IEnumerator<T>.MoveNext` is what tells the caller to stop iterating. This is implemented for you when you use `yield return`. If you wish to explicitly stop you can use `yield break`.

Comment: @poke the inconsistency is my fault in the example. Page is a made-up thing for this post, BTreePage is really what I'm returning in my real code. Fixed.

Comment: I was commenting about using `IEnumerable<T>` vs. `IEnumerator<T>`.

Comment: @poke I missed the distinction, got a link to explain more or show an example?

Comment: @Dan See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/558304/216074). Basically (since you’re coming from Python), `IEnumerable` is the generator, or the list, and `IEnumerator` would be the thing you get when you call `iter()` on it (the technical thing). Most of the time, you would want the `IEnumerable` since that’s easier to consume (e.g. using a `foreach` loop).

Comment: @poke its confusing, because if i implement it in the class, it requires two getenumerator methods, one generic <> and one not. makes no sense but errors if I don't have both

Comment: with accepted answer can't i just do `foreach (Page p in myClass)`?

Comment: No, don’t implement it. Just make your method *return* that type. I.e. instead of `IEnumerator<Page> GetEnumerator()`, change the signature to `IEnumerable<Page> GetPages()` (use a proper name too). The implementation is the same.

Comment: No, for the `foreach` to work, you need to return `IEnumerable` instead of `IEnumerator`.

Comment: @poke crap. I gotta figure this out. But that's another question I suppose

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you should use `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `IEnumerator<T>`. The enumerator is the technical object that is being used to enumerate over something. That something—in many cases–is an enumerable.

C# has special abilities to deal with enumerables. Most prominently, you can use a `foreach` loop with an enumerable (but not an enumerator; even though the loop actually uses the enumerator of the enumerable). Also, enumerables allow you to use [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693024.aspx) which makes it even more easier to consume.

So you should change your class like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    public uint myLength { get; set; }
    public uint myPageSize { get; set; }

    # note the modified signature
    public IEnumerable<Page> GetPages()
    {
        for (uint i = 1; i < this.myLength; i++)
        {
            Page p;
            try
            {
                p = new Page(this, i);
            }
            catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
            {
                yield break;
            }
            yield return p;
        }
    }
}
```

In the end, this allows you to use it like this:

```
var obj = new MyClass();

foreach (var page in obj.GetPages())
{
    // do whatever
}

// or even using LINQ
var pageOffsets = obj.GetPages().Select(p => p.currentOffset).ToList();
```

Of course, you should also change the *name* of the method to something meaningful. If you’re returning pages, `GetPages` is maybe a good first step in the right direction. The name `GetEnumerator` is kind of reserved for types implementing `IEnumerable`, where the `GetEnumerator` method is supposed to return an enumerator of the collection the object represents.

Comment: Makes much more sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The two ways to do it is let the code execution reach the end of the GetEnumerator function or put in a `yield break;` in the code, this would behave the same as a `return;` in a function that returned `void`.

From the caller's perceptive the Enumerator returned from `GetEnumerator()` will start returning `false` for `MoveNext()`, that is how they tell that the enumerator is done.

---

To fix your  "Can't yield a value inside the body of a try block with a catch clause" you put the try/catch around the wrong part of the code, the execption will be thrown on the `new` not the `yield return`. Your code should look like

```
public IEnumerator<Page> GetEnumerator()
{
    for (uint i = 1; i < this.myLength; i++)
    {
        // start count at 1 to skip first page
        Page p;
        try
        {
            p = new Page(this, i);
        }
        catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
        {
            yield break;
        }
        yield return p;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is right answer, but now I have two problems ;) -- apparently I can't use yield inside a try statement. Arg

Comment: Odd. I get "Can't yield a value inside the body of a try block with a catch clause"

Comment: Yes, [you can’t do that](http://stackoverflow.com/q/346365/216074). Just capture the value in a variable, and yield it after the try/catch.

Comment: @Dan updated answer with a full example. You should had the try around the `new` anyway, that is where the exception would happen.

Comment: awesome, so I can just do `foreach (Page in myClass)` is my goal. Thank you

Comment: @Dan One note, using a `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` is kinda a bad design choice. You should not be using exceptions for your normal program flow control. A better design choice would be do the range math inside `GetEnumerator` and only call `new Page` if it is a valid range value.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `yield break;` statement to end the sequence that your iterator method is generating.